# What is the Windows equivalent of launch-prefix="xterm -e" for launch files?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roslaunch, windows10, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am moving from Ubuntu to Windows 10 (using Melodic) and I can't seem to find the equivalent to **launch-prefix="xterm -e"** for windows. What I am trying to do is open each node in a separate window from the master when I run the launch file. Here is my launch file (with xterm still there):

```
> <launch>
> 
>     <node pkg="cpp-test"
>         type="listener"
>         name="test_listener"
>         output="screen"
>         launch-prefix="xterm -e">     </node>
>   
>     <node pkg="cpp-test"
>         type="talker"
>         name="test_talker"
>         output="screen"
>         launch-prefix="xterm -e">     </node>
> 
> </launch>
```

There is also the issue that I am not opening a standard command window, but rather a custom one from a shortcut. So my question is what command can I put in the launch file so that I can open up a separate window for the master and both nodes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321596/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-launch-prefix=%22xterm--e%22-for-launch-files?/) by [anonymous36363](https://answers.ros.org/users/36363/anonymous36363/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2019-04-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-22**:
Not an answer, but: could `start` be used here? Together with the shortcut that you use to open a "regular ROS cmd window"? Potentially append a `%*` (not sure this is needed) so that all args (ie: actual node executable path and args) are passed as args of the shortcut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a new use case for me. start is a cmd.exe intrinsic command, so cannot be used directly. However, you can use it in combination with cmd.exe:
launch-prefix="cmd.exe /K start"

This does launch the node in a new window, which correctly captures the output of the node.

However, on a cursory view, it doesn't appear to propogate the ROS command line to the launched tasks. I've created a task in the Windows porting status to track this. https://github.com/ms-iot/ROSOnWindows/issues/108.

---

Originally posted by [OoeyGUI](https://answers.ros.org/users/37999/ooeygui/) with karma: 186 on 2019-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous36363](https://answers.ros.org/users/36363/anonymous36363/) on 2019-04-23**:
Thanks, this does what I need it to do. It would be nice to have ROS command functionality too, but for now this is a good solution.